# Tangent plane to $f(x,y)=x^2ye^{1-xy}$

Tags: real-analysis

I wonder if my thoughts are correct when solving the following problem:

> Find a tangent plane to the function
>   $$f(x,y)=x^2ye^{1-xy}$$
>   at a point $((1,1),\;f(1,1))$. Express it both as a defining equation and parametric equation.

Clearly the given function can be represented using Taylor series expansion at the given point. The first **two** terms of this expansion give us linear approximation of the function at this point, which I guess will be exactly our desirable tangent plane.

So our plane using Taylor series 
$$z=f(1,1)+{\partial f\over \partial x}(1,1)(x-1)+{\partial f \over \partial y}(1,1)(y-1)\\
= 1+1\cdot (x-1) + 0\cdot (y-1)=x
$$

I obtain the plane equation $z=x$. However I am not sure the result is correct. Is there a mistake in my logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct. The normal vector to the surface 
$$g(x,y,z)=x^2 y \exp (1-x y)-z=0$$ 
is its gradient,
$$\hat{n}=\{\frac{\partial g}{\partial x},\frac{\partial g}{\partial y},\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\}=\{2 x y e^{1-x y}-x^2 y^2 e^{1-x y},x^2 e^{1-x y}-x^3 y e^{1-x y},-1\}$$
at point $(1,1,1)$ (not that $f(1,1)=1$), i.e. 
$$\hat{n}=\{1,0,-1\}.$$
Therefore, the plane equations is,
$$(1)x+(0)y+(-1)z=d \to x-z=d$$
Moreover, since point $(1,1,1)$ is on the plane, we have
$$1-1=d\to d=0$$
Therefore, finally the plane equation is,
$$x-z=0$$
In the parametric form the plane equation is,
$$x(t)=t,\,z(t)=t$$
with arbitrary $y(t).$